# Find String Start and End position multiple times

Tags: java

Would like to find the Start and End position of passwords multiple times in a given string.

I have 2 arrays
one for possible password tags combination
another for tags splitter

need to use the below 2 arrays to locate the possible password string combination and the corresponding splitter after it.

```
String[] tags = {password, pwd, passcode};
String[] splitter = {:,#,=};
```

Need to find the start and end position of password in below string

Example 1:

```
Input:
password: test123 and pwd = 123&test

Output:
test123 = 10,17
123&test = 27,36
```

Example 2:

```
Input:
passcode: test123 and passcode: 123&test

Output:
test123 = 10,17
123&test = 32,40
```

Comment: Do you have any format for string input? like string would be having this set of words.

Comment: @JaypalSodha : The format is not fixed. It can be any string. I need to search password keyword using 1st array and the splitter using 2nd array. Need to extract the password position

Comment: What would be wrong with using [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start())?

Comment: Why do you need the positions?

Comment: To extract the passwords you could use a regular expression and the Pattern and Matcher classes

Comment: @MichaelKatt : i need to mask the password, so i need to know the position

Comment: will input string always has two passwords and splitter , like `passTag`+`splitter`+`password`+`and`+`passTag`+`splitter`+`password` ?

Comment: @Sadu i added some code. have a look

Comment: @sanjeevRm : the input can differ it can have 5 password tag also. It is dynamic and the format may very.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split string by `and`

```
        String[] inputStrArr = input.split("and");
```

find the splitter to be use

```
        for(String str : inputStrArr) {
            String passStrSplt = "";
            if(str.indexOf(":") > 0) {
                passStrSplt = ":";
            } else if(str.indexOf("#") > 0) {
                passStrSplt = "#";
            } else if(str.indexOf("=") > 0) {
                passStrSplt = "=";
            }
    // get the password from each string    
           String passStr = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(passStrSplt));
           String passVal = str.substring(str.indexOf(passStrSplt)+1,str.length());
           System.out.println("passVal:"+passVal);
    // find begin and end index    
           int beginIndex = input.indexOf(passVal);
           int  endIndex = beginIndex+passVal.length(); 
           System.out.println("begin:"+beginIndex+" end:"+endIndex);
```

Output

```
    passVal: test123 
    begin:9 end:18
    
    passVal: 123&test
    begin:27 end:36
```

verify if string with begin and endIndex matches expected password

```
    String extractedPass = input.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    System.out.println("extractedPass "+extractedPass);
```

Output ExtractedPass

```
    extractedPass  test123 
    
    extractedPass  123&test
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the passwords you could use a regular expression and the Pattern and Matcher classes.

here an example

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Pwd {

    private Pwd() {
        super();
    }

    public static String maskPwd(String input) {

        String regex = "(?:password|pwd|passcode) ?[:#=] ?([a-zA-Z0-9&]+)\s?";
        Pattern pwdPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher pwdMatcher = pwdPattern.matcher(input);

        StringBuilder maskedInput = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFollowingPwd = false;
        int previousEnd = -1;
        while (pwdMatcher.find()) {

            if (isFollowingPwd) {
                int start = pwdMatcher.start(1);
                int end = pwdMatcher.end(1);

                maskedInput.append(input.substring(previousEnd, start));
                appendMaskSign(start, end, maskedInput);

                previousEnd = end;
            } else {
                int start = pwdMatcher.start(1);
                int end = pwdMatcher.end(1);

                maskedInput.append(input.substring(0, start));
                appendMaskSign(start, end, maskedInput);

                isFollowingPwd = true;
                previousEnd = end;
            }
        }
        maskedInput.append(input.substring(previousEnd, input.length()));

        return maskedInput.toString();
    }

    private static void appendMaskSign(int start, int end, StringBuilder maskedInput) {
        int signCounter = end - start;
        for (int i = 0; i < signCounter; i++) {
            maskedInput.append("*");
        }
    }
}
```

and some Junit5 tests, which passed

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class PwdTest {

    @Test
    void mask() {
        String actual = Pwd.maskPwd("password: test123 and pwd = 123&test");

        String expected = "password: ******* and pwd = ********";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    void mask2() {
        String actual = Pwd.maskPwd("passcode: test123 and passcode: 123&test");

        String expected = "passcode: ******* and passcode: ********";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    void mask3() {
        String actual = Pwd.maskPwd("password: test123 and passcode= 123&test and pwd# 987&test");

        String expected = "password: ******* and passcode= ******** and pwd# ********";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

The code will also work with more than 2 passwords (look at mask3()).